# Terminal output to a file using >

Tags: linux, bash, arm

I'm a beginner with bash/linux. I have a program that I have written using Visual Code Studio. I have been able to correctly compile the program and it return the output I was expecting. But I have forgotten the command to take that output and put it into a specific file.

Also, how would I find the pathway for that file, if it's not physically on my computer? I've ssh into a rasp pi on campus. So all the files are on the pi. Could it be as simple as copy paste?

Answer (score 1):

I really think you should go over the basics of remote connection to a Linux machine, but to answer your question:

In order to redirect output from a command line utility (i.e. your program):
`./[program_name] &> [output file]`
using the `&>` operator will redirect both stdout and stderr to that file which I assume you want

In order to pull that file from remote:
`scp [username]@[server_ip]:/[output file] ./`

This assumes you actually have a user on that remote machine that you can `ssh` into